# Query to return the category with the max SUM value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

[image]

I am trying to find the "source" with the highest income. In this case the "Ads".

Should I make combined query to find the SUM of each "source", then a second query to find the MAX value among them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Just use `order by` with `limit`:

```
select source, sum(amount)
from t
group by source
order by sum(amount) desc
limit 1;
```